# Multipart Erro : Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength

Tags: swift, image, upload, alamofire, multipart

I trying to make a upload using Alamofire, but return one erro : responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength), anyone knows what this ?

my code :

```
let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img12345")
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)!

    let parameters = ["Cookie": UsersService.get()?.kID]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: key)
        }
    },to:"http://\(ServersService.getAtual()!.host)/hnzacerto/HnzAcertoViagemUploader")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```

Thanks